# How to connect to remote mongodb with php?

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is the php code that I'm working with in my local machine:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db=$m->selectDB("def");
//then all in my code i use $db to select insert ... (as defined in php doc)
```

Now I want to connect my application to a remote server (hosted by mongood.com)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use mongoOd without the REST API
But remember, it's a replica Set cluster so You need to configure your PHP for a ReplicaSet configuration...

I use mongoOd within ruby & mongoid (not the REST API)

Here a php example

```
<?php
  // connecting to mongood.com cluster
  $m = new Mongo("mongodb://94.23.54.103:27017,188.165.219.99:27017,94.23.220.151:27017", array("replicaSet" => "cluster"));
  var_dump($m);
  $db = $m->selectDB('my_database');
  $db->authenticate("my_login", "my_password");
  $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'my_collection');
  $cursor = $collection->find();
  foreach ($cursor as $doc) { var_dump($doc); }
?>
```

Enjoy :)

A mongoOd Team member

Answer (score 3):

The constructor for the mongo object takes as its arguments connection parameters.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php

`$m = new Mongo('mongodb://[username:password]@host:port')`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to ask them what the connection URI is, and then use:

```
$m = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@hostname");
```

However, I am not sure if that option is available to you. Their website says you can access data via a REST API.

At any rate, you should ask them for help. There's a button on the left that reads "aide," if you click on it you'll get a form where you can fill in your email and your question.

**Reference: [Mongo - Connecting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php)**

Comment: yep, thats what i tryed but they want rest indeed; i will check with them, thanks